# How to match an exact word inside a string?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

```
op = ['TRAIL_RATE_ID 8 TRAIL_RATE_NAME VC-4 TRAIL_ORDER High Order ',    'TRAIL_RATE_ID 9 TRAIL_RATE_NAME VC4-4 TRAIL_ORDER High Order ' , 'TRAIL_RATE_ID 10 TRAIL_RATE_NAME VC-8 TRAIL_ORDER High Order ']
word = "8"
for op1 in op:
    pp=re.search('(\\b'+word +'\\b)', op1, flags=re.IGNORECASE|re.DOTALL)
    print bool(pp)
```

matches 2 occurrences of 8.

I want it to match only the first occurrence. The word can be
    word= "8"
    word = "$#hhd"
    word = "hi hello"

How do I match this using regex?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can require that there should not be a non-whitespace symbol on both sides of the word:

```
r'(?<!\S){0}(?!\S)'.format(re.escape(word))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aY8zM7/1)

I added `re.escape(word)` in case your keywords contain special regex metacharacters that should be treated literally.

See [Python demo](http://ideone.com/1PzQ3v):

```
import re
word = "8"
pat = r'(?<!\S){0}(?!\S)'.format(re.escape(word))
print re.search(pat,"nnn 8", flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

Comment: Also, use raw string literals when defining regex patterns in Python - saves much headache.

Comment: This should be the correct answer - `Python` does only support a **fixed width** lookbehind (+1). Read more about Wiktor's solution on ie [**The double negative delimiter**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-boundaries.html#double-negative-delimiter)

Comment: @Jan: More, the alternative branches inside a lookbehind should be of equal length. `(?<=\s|\d)` will work.

Comment: Glad it works, please consider accepting the answer then. It is shorter, uses much less resources as the number of lookbehinds is 1 (and there is no alternation in my pattern - and unanchored lookbehinds are costly in terms of performance), and is more readable. And you do not need any extra flags with this pattern (but a `re.I` if you need to ignore case).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew `'(?<!\S){0}(?!\S)' `this works perfectly and it only matches the specific word but is there a way to modify the regex so it will also matches the same words that end with `? or punctuation.` as well. I really can't figure out a way.

Comment: @SaiKumar Try `r'(?<!\S){0}[^\w\s]?(?!\S)'`. Probably, it is not quite that, I'd need more input, sample strings to match and those where these matches should be avoided.

Answer (score 4):

Word boundaries won't help because `-` is not considered a word character.

You can use lookarounds:

```
p = re.compile(r'(?:(?<=^)|(?<=\s))' + word + r'(?=\s|$)', flags=re.IGNORECASE|re.M)
re.search(p, op1)
```

[Code Demo](http://ideone.com/euVKrD)

- `(?<=^)|(?<=\s)` is a lookbehind to ensure we have line start or whitespace before our word
- `(?=\s|$)` is a lookahead to ensure we have line end or whitespace next to our word

Comment: Regardless how many upvotes this answer gets (`re.search('(?<=\\s|^)' + word + '(?=\\s|$)', op1, flags=re.IGNORECASE|re.M)`), it won't become correct. Please check before upvoting, or the whole point of upvoting/downvoting is pointless.

Comment: Yes you're right Wiktor. It is corrected now. Sorry had to step away to attend a meeting. I am not core python developer and was fooled by regex101 code generator :)